# What is var/plugins.json and should it go into version control (Shopware 6.3.5.2)?

Tags: shopware

On a quite fresh setup I ran

```
bin/build-storefront.sh
```

Now var/plugins.json is on the list of changed files in git. Now I am wondering if I should commit this file, because it contains local absolute paths - which might be different on other systems:

[image: Local Path in var/plugins.json]

*EDIT:* The file seems to be recreated during build, when I deleted it. However it's in the [production-template git repository](https://github.com/shopware/production/blob/6.3/var/plugins.json) which is strange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`var/plugins.json` is auto generated by `build-administration.sh` and `build-storefront.sh` to set entry points and output files for Webpack for the installed plugins.

This file should not be commited. If you commit, it will be replaced anyway. It will be ignored by git in the upcoming version of Shopware 6.4 (see [the commit](https://github.com/shopware/production/commit/cc0158cf046917692eb679750bba1d1efcf70763#diff-bc37d034bad564583790a46f19d807abfe519c5671395fd494d8cce506c42947)).

Comment: Please read that commit properly: `Do not ignore var/plugins.json`

Comment: @NicoHaase the comment is wrong. A better message would be "Do not exclude var/plugins.json in .gitignore". Please read the code and and the linked [ticket](https://github.com/shopware/production/pull/89).